# Firebase owner permissions

Tags: firebase

Tell me please. If the project firebase has 2 owners, how can one of the owners limit access to managing user roles?

There is no admin role, only owner. How to create a role that gets all the rights, except for editing other roles?

Answer (score 3):

There are currently 3 roles you can assign to any user to use your database.

***Owner:*** Full access to all Firebase and Google Cloud Platform resources, such as user administration, permissions and billing.

***Editor:*** it's almost like the owner, but instead you can Access to edit all Firebase and Google Cloud Platform resources and can't access to any user administration, permissions or billing.

***Writer:*** Read access on all Firebase and Google Cloud Platform resources.

Beyond that, there is no other permissions to grant to any user in your project; make sure that one of these fits to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Firebase version, You can click on `Assign Firebase Roles` And select the rights of the user/users.
[image: Like this]